# Optimising efficiency in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a simple program here which is set to produce the output,

```
The value of a is 2005

The value of b is 1959

The value of c is 1

The value of d is 0

The value of (a - b) * (c + d) is 46
```

I'm looking for the best ways to optimize my code, I'm repeating code ALOT! is it possible to print straight from other registers? e.g SWI 0 but for a integer not in R0?

```
    B   main
aval    DEFW    2005
bval    DEFW    1959
cval    DEFW    1
dval    DEFW    0
valOf   DEFB    'The value of \0'
isStr   DEFB    ' is \0'
lstStr  DEFB    'The value of (a - b) * (c + d) is \0'

    ALIGN

main    ADR R0, valOf   ;Value a
    SWI 3       
    MOV R0, #97     
    SWI 0       
    ADR R0, isStr   
    SWI 3
    LDR R0, aval    
    SWI 4
    MOV R0, #10     ;print new line
    SWI 0

    ADR R0, valOf   ;Value b
    SWI 3
    MOV R0, #98
    SWI 0
    ADR R0, isStr   
    SWI 3
    LDR R0, bval    
    SWI 4
    MOV R0, #10     ;print new line
    SWI 0

    ADR R0, valOf   ;Value c
    SWI 3
    MOV R0, #99
    SWI 0
    ADR R0, isStr   
    SWI 3
    LDR R0, cval    
    SWI 4
    MOV R0, #10     ;print new line
    SWI 0

    ADR R0, valOf   ;print 'value of '
    SWI 3
    MOV R0, #100
    SWI 0
    ADR R0, isStr   ;
    SWI 3
    LDR R0, dval    
    SWI 4   
    MOV R0, #10     ;print new line
    SWI 0

    ADR     R0, lstStr
    SWI 3
    LDR R3, aval
    LDR R4, bval
    LDR R5, cval
    LDR R6, dval
    SUB R1, R3, R4
    SUB R2, R5, R6
    MUL R0, R1, R2
    SWI 4

    SWI 2       ;exit
```

Any thoughts much appreciated :)

Comment: ARM is really fragmented, you also should specify what platform are you targeting, by the way i think that in your case you should do this in C or C++.

Comment: I can see i should of added more information about the question which i shall do next time :) This question is just for learning purposes hence why im not writing it in C, and it is also sitting on top of Linux being run in the Komodo emulator. Still, thanks for the insightful answers guys! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to ask if you have to write in assembly but since you are using `SWI` (nowadays it is called [SVC](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihidabi.html)) obviously you are sitting on top of an OS, high chance Linux.

Why you are not writing in C? That should be much easier for you except if this is solely for learning purposes which in that case why you would try to learn such a usage?

About optimization, when your are sitting on top of a non-real-time OS and make system calls any performance expectation will be just lost. From the point of software interrupt kernel can delay your code variably and un-guaranteed fashion.

So in this case if you are thinking about making your application fast, try to reduce number of system calls by preparing / caching print buffers in userspace where you can apply some plain and easy C idioms.

Comment: This is purely for learning purposes, im sitting on top of linux using Komodo emulator. Yes i can see i needed to add more information here about the question but i shall do so next time! I'll have a go adding in the C idioms. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your definition of 'optimise' is less code (rather than, say, speed), you might begin by considering the possibility of using subroutines to do the grunt work. That way, you can load the string into R0, the value into R1 and then call the subroutine.

The steps such as register transfers and the various swi calls would be done at one point (also making things a lot easier if the format were to change) and the main code reduces from about ten lines to about three for each thing output (a couple of register loads and a call).

Comment: Btw, some assemblers also offer macro support. It can be useful as well.

Comment: Totally agree with this: the `SWI` traps are the dominant factor in performance of this code.  You really ought to be string concatenation and integer to string conversion in user-space using functions. 

If you're worried about efficiency of writing code, I'd thoroughly recommend using C.